# scroll back to the previous collectionview cell

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am using the code below to scroll to the next cell which works perfectly but how do I scroll back to the previous cell?

```
 let cellItems = CollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
            CollectionView.scrollToItem(at: cellItems.max()!, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `indexPathsForVisibleItems` method does not guarantee order. You need to sort it firstly:

```
let sortedIndexes = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted(<)
```

If you want to scroll to the previous cell, you need to store previous cell `IndexPath` somewhere in your class:

```
var previousCellIndexPath: IndexPath?
```

And than you can scroll to this cell:

```
func scrollToPreviousCell() {
    guard let previousCellIndexPath = self.previousCellIndexPath else { return }
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: previousIndexPath, at: centeredVertically, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Hi Llya thanks for the reply. Ok I got the preiousCellIndexPath but for some reason the collectionView.scrollToItem(at: previousIndexPath has jumped to random other IndexPaths. And I'm not sure why?

Comment: What `IndexPath` do you set to previousCellIndexPath?